# Gradle resolving only one of two dependencies at a time

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, build.gradle

I have a Gradle project which consists of three modules. Let's call them A, B, and C. Module C uses both A and B. So it has:

```
implementation project(":A:api")
implementation project(":B:api")
```

However, after successfully building the project, in module C, Intellij still cannot find classes from A, only from B. And if I delete B from dependencies, it starts to see A. Do you know what's going on?

Below are the build.gradle files of all three modules. Module D is another module used by all these three modules.

build.gradle file of module C.

```
plugins {
    id "mycompany.impl-conventions"
    id "mycompany.grpc-conventions"
    id "mycompany.api-conventions"
    id "application"
}

group = "mycompany"
version = "2.0.0"
sourceCompatibility = "11"
targetCompatibility = "11"

setDescription("Project C")

def mainClassPath = "mycompany.C.Main"

dependencies {
    implementation project(":A:api")
    implementation project(":B:api")
    implementation project(":D")
    implementation project(":D:internal")

    implementation "com.beust:jcommander:1.78"
}

application {
    mainClass.set(mainClassPath)
}
```

The build.gradle file of module A is:

```
plugins {
    id "mycompany.api-conventions"
}

group = "mycompany"
version = "2.0.0"
sourceCompatibility = "8"
targetCompatibility = "11"

ext.setProperty(PACKAGE_NAME, "A-api")
ext.setProperty(DISPLAY_NAME, "A API")
setDescription("API for the services of A.")

dependencies {
    implementation project(":D")
}

task publishApi {
    if (version.matches("^${VERSION_PATTERN}\$")) {
        dependsOn publishMaven
        dependsOn publishNpm
    }
}

task releaseApi {
    if (version.matches("^${VERSION_PATTERN}\$")) {
        dependsOn deployApi
    }
}
```

And for module B.

```
plugins {
    id "mycompany.api-conventions"
}

group = "mycompany"
version = "9.1.1"
sourceCompatibility = "8"
targetCompatibility = "11"

ext.setProperty(PACKAGE_NAME, "B-api")
ext.setProperty(DISPLAY_NAME, "B API")
setDescription("API for the services of B.")

dependencies {
    implementation project(":D")
}

task publishApi {
    if (version.matches("^${VERSION_PATTERN}\$")) {
        dependsOn publishMaven
        dependsOn publishNpm
    }
}

task releaseApi {
    if (version.matches("^${VERSION_PATTERN}\$")) {
        dependsOn deployApi
    }
}
```

Comment: Can u share the build.gradle file ?

Comment: I added the files to the question, thanks.

Comment: Please prepare and provide a small reproducible project sample https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.

Comment: Try to clear IDE caches. `File | Invalidate Caches... | Invalidate and Restart`